# Differently named parameters of OperationContracts with same name in single ServiceContract?

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I need to modify one of the Operation Contracts in my WCF service in a slight way.

What I have already (just a plain example)

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWCF
{
[OperationContract]
void GetMessage(string a, string b, string c);

[OperationContract]
void GetData(string a, string b, string c);
}
```

But I need for one single case, change one of the parameter names to another in this manner that the whole interface would look the same except for that single change

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWCF
{
[OperationContract]
void GetMessage(string a, string THIS_NAME_HAS_CHANGED, string c);

[OperationContract]
void GetData(string a, string b, string c);
}
```

This is because one of my endpoints will only accept the old name but all other ones will accept the new name. I would like this to be done as part of my application module but after I find solution I will handle this myself so no need to post that part of code here.

Comment: Have your service implement / expose both interfaces (named differently of course to satisfy C# language rules; possibly use `[ServiceContract(Name = "")]` to expose a different name to the outside): the one with old parameter name and the one with the new parameter name. Bound two different endpoints. Give the "old client" one endpoint and the others the other endpoint.

Comment: The issue is I CANNOT expose different name to the outside. In both cases the names must be the same, the only thing that CAN AND MUST change is the parameter name in that precise exposed OperationContract. The ServiceDefinition at the other side must remain unchanged and fit THIS_NAME_HAS_CHANGED parameter before the change. It cannot be upgraded.